# Is there anyway to re-ingest data from a Kinesis Firehose stream from a point in time?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We ingest a large volume of event data via AWS Lambda-->Kinesis Firehose-->Redshift.  My question; Is there anyway to re-ingest Firehose stream data from s3 by time (or other checkpoint), say if we wanted to load the stream data to another cluster?

Comment: Just to clarify... Are you saying that an AWS Lambda function (triggered by something) will push data into an Amazon Kinesis Firehose? Also, what do you mean by "load the stream data to another cluster"?

Comment: Yes, the data is coming in via Lambda and streaming via s3 into Redshift.  Since Firehose uses Redshift COPY commands and manifests to load the data to Redshift, I thought presumably there might be a way to ingest the data from S3 to another table in the same or different cluster.

Comment: Are you wanting to ingest the SAME data (into a different table), or different data into S3?